# ¿ Porque la imagen no se muestra cuando compilo el comando npm run build, en React ?

Tags: reactjs, extensión-google-chrome

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy importando una imagen y con el comando npm start si se muestra, pero cuando hago el comando npm run build, resulta que no aparece, pero navegando en su DOM, su ruta esta bien. Leyendo me encontre que lo correcto son importarlas y asi lo tengo

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import imagen1 from '../img/vaso.jpg';
// const imagen1 = require('../img/vaso.jpg');
export default class ElementosSeenapse extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
     <div>
       <img className = 'container-starbucks'
         src = {imagen1}
         alt = "deberia aparecer una imagen"/>
     </div>
   );
  }
}
```

incluso ya use la opciòn de require.. y nada,
las rutas son, src/components/Elementos.jsx y la imagen esta en src/img/vaso.jpg

Les adjunto un screenshot, para que observen que error me arroja, pero que a la vez la ruta si esta bien, pues la genera con todo y su sha. Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias ! 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y la imagen puede ser vista desde en el navegador? Si usas webpack y tienes más de un webpack.config, tienes soporte para la imagen?

Comment: en caso que la carpeta este en la raiz
import imagen1 from './img/vaso.jpg';